# Python Moviepy module: output video?

Tags: python, input, error-handling, python-module, moviepy

So basically, my code is supposed to edit the videos in a given directory for the first 15 seconds, the middle 15 seconds, and the last 15 seconds. I'm on python 2.7 and i'm using the moviepy module.

```
import moviepy.editor as mp
from moviepy.editor import *
import os

for item in os.listdir(wildcard):
    clip = VideoFileClip(vid + item)
    dur = clip.duration
    firstHalf = (dur/2.0) - 7.5
    secHalf = (dur/2.0) + 7.5
    end = dur - 15.0
    clip1 = clip.subclip(0, 15.0)
    clip2 = clip.subclip(firstHalf, secHalf)
    clip3 = clip.subclip(end, int(dur))
    video = mp.concatenate([clip1,clip2,clip3])
    video.to_videofile(wildcard, fps=24, codec='mpeg4')
```

But I keep getting an error at the video = mp.concatenate() line. I'm not sure why, but it outputs the message "Errno 22: Invalid Argument."

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the whole error message ?

Here are some things you can try:

```
mp.concatenate
```

should be replaced with

```
mp.concatenate_videofiles
```

and

```
video.to_videofile(wildcard, fps=24)
```

should be replaced with

```
video.write_videofile("some_name.mp4", fps=24)
```